# Issue with .replace function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a Google sheet that collects registration data from customers. Included in the data collected is a student's name, the session the student elected to attend and a credit card number. Once a submission has been made, I get a notification. Upon notification, I go to my Google sheet and charge the credit card the appropriate amount.

Once the credit card has been charged, I then want to generate a confirmation email to the customer, which is based on a text template in cell A1, i.e., (1,1) on sheet2, that includes the student's name (Range C2), the session the student registered to attend (range D2) and the amount charged to the credit card (Range E2). Simply put, I want to replace curly bracket placeholders in my "template text" (i.e., {Name},{sessions} and {Cost} with the actual values which I've defined as variables.

For the life of me, I cannot get this to work.

Here's the error detail I get when I try to run this code:

> Type Error:  Cannot find function replace in object This is the email body.  This is the amount charged to the credit card: {Cost}.

I've been all over the web on this.  I've watched YouTube videos. I've read what seems like mountains of online documentation, none of which has provided any meaningful help.  I've frustrated myself trying to figure out how the logger works and still, it's a complete mystery to me.  Very frustrated!

Also, is there a way I can share my project with the forum community so someone out there can actually look at my code in action???  I wish there was a site for Apps Script that works like the ExcelForum does for questions about VBA programming.

```
function SendEmail2() {
  // fetch these values as you need
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2").getValues();
  var studentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C2").getValues();
  var sessionRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D2").getValues();
  var chargeAmt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("E2").getValues();

  var studentName = studentRange;
  var sessionName = sessionRange;
  var emailAddress = emailRange;
  var charge = chargeAmt;

  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValues();

  // This is what needed to change
  var emailText = templateText
     .replace("{Name}", studentName)
     .replace("{Sessions}", sessionName)
     .replace("{Cost}", charge);

  var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
  var message = emailText;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 

}
```

This is the email body.

This is the amount charged to credit card `{Cost}` `// should be replaced with the value of the var "charge".`

This is the student's name: `{Name}`.  `//Should be replaced with the value associated to the var "studentName"]`

These are the sessions the student is scheduled to attend: `{Sessions}`  `//Should be the value associated with the var "sessionName".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your script is trying to do replace on whatever values it gets, but the values are not treated as a string, therefore .replace will not work as you're expecting.

Try using .toString() like below, I've also cleaned up some of the other variables in your script as there's no real reason to define then rename them.

```
function SendEmail2() {

  //spreadsheet variables
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //fetch values from spreadsheet
  var emailAddress = dataSheet.getRange("B2").getValues();
  var studentName = dataSheet.getRange("C2").getValues();
  var sessionName = dataSheet.getRange("D2").getValues();
  var charge = dataSheet.getRange("E2").getValues();
  var templateText = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1,1).getValues();

  //get templateText as string and replace values with variables defined above
  var emailText = templateText.toString()
     .replace("{Name}", studentName)
     .replace("{Sessions}", sessionName)
     .replace("{Cost}", charge);

  var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
  var message = emailText;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
}
```

As you can see I have added .toString() at the start of your replace:

```
var emailText = templateText.toString()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ross!  It works perfectly.  More importantly, I understand the changes you made in the code so I've learned something too!

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Please mark this as the answer to your question if you're satisfied.